# Docker with Django/PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm a novice on Docker and I actually try this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

There are several things that I don't understand:

- The "code" folder is never created.
- Once the container is launched with the "docker-compose up"
  command, how can I access to the postgreSQL command line ?
- In the tutorial, at the "Create a Django project" part, the first point is
  "Change to the root of your project directory." But if I understand
  correctly the tutorial, I'm already in this folder.

Someone can help me ? thanks by advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - The "code" folder is never created.

Code folder is mounted to docker container from current directory, according to docker-compose.yml. So after run command in docker container there will be directory code (you can prove that by `docker-compose run web ls /code`), but on your local OS not.

> - Once the container is launched with the "docker-compose up" command, how can I access to the postgreSQL command line ?

You can connect by port:
`docker-compose run db psql -U postgres`.

Or by django dbshell:
`docker-compose run web python manage.py dbshell`

> In the tutorial, at the "Create a Django project" part, the first point is "Change to the root of your project directory." But if I understand correctly the tutorial, I'm already in this folder.

If you're already in project root dire, than you can skip step, but always keep in mind that current directory will be mounted to /code dir in container.